# python web-scraping searching attributes names

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

> I am using web.pattern library and I want to extract the tables from
>   the webpage with a certain class name. The code below is giving me a
>   KeyError: 'class'

```
def get_tables_by_Class(html):
    dom = web.Element(html)
    for t in dom.by_tag('table'):
         if t.attrs['class'] == 'class Name' :
            tbls = t 
    return tbls
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here and I wish to know is there any other way of targeting specific element's attributes using "Pattern" and if there is a way of doing that in "Beautiful Soup"

Answer (score 0):

In BeautifulSoup you can use `find_all()` to find tags with a given attribute:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_tables_by_Class(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    return soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class': 'class Name'})
```

Alternatively you can use `class_`:

```
return soup.find_all('table', class_='class Name')
```

This does what i think your code is trying to do, i.e. return a list of tables of a particular class, however, your code, if it worked, would actually return the last table found of the required class, not all of them.

The fact that you get a key error suggests that not all of the tables in the HTML document actually have a `class` attribute, and therefore `class` is not stored in the `attrs` dictionary for those tables. Attempting a dictionary lookup for a non-existent key will produce the error that you see. You can fix this by handling the exception and ignoring `KeyError`:

```
for t in dom.by_tag('table'):
    try:
        if t.attrs['class'] == 'class Name' :
            tbls = t
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Or, you can use `dict.get()` to lookup a key in the dictionary without raising an exception if the key is missing:

```
for t in dom.by_tag('table'):
    if t.attrs.get('class') == 'class Name' :
        tbls = t
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access any attributes easily using BeautifulSoup.

See:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<table class="table-bordered" width="100%">
    <!-- childrens here -->
</table>

<table class="table-stripped" width="100%">
    <!-- childrens here -->
</table>
'''

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

tt = html_soup.find_all('table')

for table in tt:
    print(table['class'])
    print(table['width'])
```